# Fetch component of std::complex as reference

Tags: c++, std

Do std::real(my_complex) and my_complex.real() make copies of the real part?  Is there a way I can access by reference instead of value?

---

For background,
I am writing some performance critical code.  Within tight loops I have to do some complex * real multiplies.  I found it is faster to do two real multiplies than a complex multiply, because I know one of the operands is real.  To support real multiplies, I store my complex data as [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA), `std::complex<std::vector<short>>`.  Maybe this is a bad idea but I thought it would make it obvious to the reader that this is complex data stored as structure of arrays.

Anyway, in tight loop I do something like the following:

```
std::real(complex_data)[0] * all_real_data[0]
std::imag(complex_data)[0] * all_real_data[0]
```

Turns out the real and imag lookups are big offender in the CPU usage report.

I tried `complex_data.real()[0] * all_real_data[0]`, but it seems to be no different.

I then abstracted the real/imag deference out of the loop like
`std::vector<short>& my_complex_real = std::real(complex_data)` and it is 2x faster.

I guess subquestion is "Is SOA inside a `std::complex` a bad idea?"

Comment: You can find the entire interface for [`std::complex` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex). There doesn't seem to be an obvious way.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on *why* you ask about this? What is the *actual* problem you have? Perhaps you should ask about that instead?

Comment: They do, logically, take copies. That does not mean that the copiled code will actually make redundant copies. The optimiser can see through that kind of thing.

Comment: @RichardHodges isnt it possible that a complex might store `abs` and `arg` internally

Comment: `complex_data.real()[0]` seems weird. Are you having an array as the data-type for `std::complex`? What for? What is the use-case? If it *is* an array you have as data, then of course it will be slow as it needs to be copied in full. Can't you have an array of plain `std::complex<double>` instead? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: "SOA" means "structure of arrays" if you don't know this particular term of art, the question doesn't really make any sense. In graphics and some other domains, one might store all of the X coordinates of a set of points adjacent to each other so one can manipulate just that coordinate with better memory/cache/register locality. It is a valid data organization tradeoff to make, but probably not inside of std::complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `std::real` and `std::complex::real` give you the real part by value, which means they make a copy.

The only way you can access the real and imaginary parts of a `std::complex<T>` is to cast it into an array.  If you have

```
std::complex<T> foo;
```

Then

```
reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(foo)[0]
```

gives you a reference to the real part and

```
reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(foo)[1]
```

gives you a reference to the imaginary part.  This is mandated to work per the standard ([complex.numbers]/4) so it is not undefined behavior.

---

You should also note the `std::complex` is only defined for `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, and `std::complex<long double>`. Any other instantiation is unspecified per  [complex.numbers]/2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the SOA idea here will be particularly productive. I assume you are having to put in global arithmetic overloads for the std::vector to make this work. But internally this also means there are two resizable vectors and two extra pointers, which is a fair bit of overhead for the kind of applications where SOA vs AOS is important. It is also gives the reason there is significant cost in extracting the real part: the vector itself is almost certainly being copied.

@NathanOliver's answer above gives a way to get a pointer to the std::complex as an array, which will likely save the copying, but I expect you will want to at least use a custom class instead of `std::vector<short>`. Realistically complex arithmetic is simple enough to implement that it may be faster to just do that part yourself.

(Daniel H's answer is better than mine in indicating it isn't allowed by the spec and calling out cache locality specifically. You really don't want to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::complex<std::vector<short>>` is unspecified behavior. The [only allowed specializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), unless you have a compiler extension, are specializations `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, and `std::complex<long double>`. Other arithmetic types, like `std::complex<short>`, are at least more likely to have sane results in practice even if they don’t have any stronger requirements in theory.

Because of cache locality, I would expect that `std::vector<std::complex<short>>` would have better performance, even if both types happen to work well in your implementation.

Either way, as NathanOliver points out above, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` should give references to the real and imaginary parts, but note that complex numbers define an `operator*` for multiplying by the real type, so this shouldn’t be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So I knocked up this little example on godbolt.

I'm struggling to see the problem with taking copies:

```
#include <complex>
#include <array>

std::complex<double> foo(std::complex<double> (& complex_data)[10], double (&all_real_data)[10], int i)
{
    return std::complex<double>(std::real(complex_data[i]) * all_real_data[i], 
        std::imag(complex_data[i]) * all_real_data[i]);
}

std::array<std::complex<double>, 10>
calc(std::complex<double> (& complex_data)[10], double (&all_real_data)[10])
{
    std::array<std::complex<double>, 10> result;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = foo(complex_data, all_real_data, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

compile with `-O3` on gcc yields for calc:

```
calc(std::complex<double> (&) [10], double (&) [10]):
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]
  mov rax, rdi
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+8], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+24]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+8]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+16]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+24], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+40]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+16], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+16]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+32]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+40], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+56]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+32], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+24]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+48]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+56], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+72]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+48], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+32]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+64]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+72], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+88]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+64], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+40]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+80]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+88], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+104]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+80], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+48]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+96]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+104], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+120]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+96], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+56]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+112]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+120], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+136]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+112], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+64]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+128]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+136], xmm1
  movsd xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi+152]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+128], xmm0
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+72]
  mulsd xmm1, xmm0
  mulsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+144]
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+152], xmm1
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+144], xmm0
  ret
```

with `-march=native` we touch memory fewer times

```
calc(std::complex<double> (&) [10], double (&) [10]):
  vmovupd ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
  vmovupd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32]
  mov rax, rdi
  vmovupd ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rdx]
  vunpckhpd ymm2, ymm1, ymm0
  vunpcklpd ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
  vpermpd ymm2, ymm2, 216
  vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 216
  vmulpd ymm0, ymm0, ymm3
  vmulpd ymm2, ymm2, ymm3
  vpermpd ymm1, ymm0, 68
  vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 238
  vpermpd ymm3, ymm2, 68
  vpermpd ymm2, ymm2, 238
  vshufpd ymm1, ymm1, ymm3, 12
  vshufpd ymm0, ymm0, ymm2, 12
  vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm1
  vmovupd ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+64]
  vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32], ymm0
  vmovupd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+96]
  vmovupd ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
  vunpckhpd ymm2, ymm1, ymm0
  vunpcklpd ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
  vpermpd ymm2, ymm2, 216
  vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 216
  vmulpd ymm0, ymm0, ymm3
  vmulpd ymm2, ymm2, ymm3
  vpermpd ymm1, ymm0, 68
  vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 238
  vpermpd ymm3, ymm2, 68
  vpermpd ymm2, ymm2, 238
  vshufpd ymm1, ymm1, ymm3, 12
  vshufpd ymm0, ymm0, ymm2, 12
  vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdi+64], ymm1
  vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdi+96], ymm0
  vmovsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+64]
  vmulsd xmm1, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+136]
  vmulsd xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+128]
  vmovsd QWORD PTR [rdi+136], xmm1
  vmovsd QWORD PTR [rdi+128], xmm0
  vmovsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+72]
  vmulsd xmm1, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+152]
  vmulsd xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+144]
  vmovsd QWORD PTR [rdi+152], xmm1
  vmovsd QWORD PTR [rdi+144], xmm0
  vzeroupper
  ret
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP isn’t using a specified `std::complex` specialization, but `std::complex<std::vector<short>>`. It seems to work with his compiler despite being unspecified, but they’re more expensive to copy. I think the solution is to not use SOA architecture.